# How to detect writing direction from language code?

Tags: python

Is it possible to detect natural writing direction using language code?

Something like:

```
get_language_direction("EN") # >>> LTR
get_language_direction("AR") # >>> RTL
```

Comment: Why is `AR` right to left?

Comment: @thedemons OMG! Check this: https://www.andiamo.co.uk/resources/right-to-left-languages/

Comment: How do I suppose to know `AR` stands for Arabic in this context, and what is your question actually? Are you trying to determine if some string is RTL or determine if `["AR", "AZ",..]` is RTL?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I wanted to check it using the "language code" which is 2-letter unique code belongs to a language.

Comment: Why not just hard coded a list and check if it's in that list?

Comment: Maybe it can be the last option if I can't find any more elegant way to do it. :(

Comment: Well, the list of countries doesn't change that often so I don't think making the list any inelegant.

Comment: Okay then, can you please post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @UmutÇağdaşCoşkun part of the problem is that a string may contain more than one language. Some languages can be written in more than one script, so even restricting ourselves to iso-639-1,  does ha (Hausa) mean ha-Latn or ha-Arab. Other languages also have multiple writing systems. Because of the complexities involved, in our internal projects we have is_bidi(), dominant_script(), dominant_strong_direction(), and first_strong() for various text processing functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to segment all current or historical scripts in this way. Scripts can be

- written vertically top-to-bottom, e.g. [Hangul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul) and [Han](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_characters)
- written vertically bottom-to-top, e.g. [Hanunoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanunoo_script)
- written both vertically and left-to-right, e.g. Hangul
- written both left-to-right and right-to-left, e.g. [Runic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runes)
- not representable on a screen, e.g. [Leke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leke_script) or the [Moon System of Embossed Reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_type)
- associated with multiple languages, e.g. [Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille)
- one of many variants associated with the same language, e.g. [Syriac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syriac_alphabet), Esṭrangēlā Syriac, Serṭā Syriac, and Maḏnḥāyā Syriac
- almost certainly more inconsistencies...

Were you to want to do this "properly" you would need to use [BCP 47](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt) to associate languages with their scripts as [ISO 15924](https://www.unicode.org/iso15924/iso15924-codes.html) doesn't seem to have done this. Then, as [thedemons suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74170490/how-to-detect-writing-direction-from-language-code#comment130953134_74170490), maintain a list of scripts and the directions text can be in.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think languages in ISO-639-1 is enough for me: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes I'm going to make a list...